# How can I merge PDF files with Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, merge

Using Perl, how can I combine or merge the sample PDF files into a single PDF file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?appendpdf.pl) can do this quite easily, and has a simple command-line front end to help.  Note: I'm the author of that library.  Example:

```
appendpdf.pl file1.pdf file2.pdf outfile.pdf
```

---

From the SYNOPSIS section of the [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.59/lib/CAM/PDF.pm):

```
my $anotherpdf = CAM::PDF->new('test2.pdf');
$pdf->appendPDF($anotherpdf);
```

Comment: There was a bug in CAM::PDF prior to April 2011 where the append might be corrupt if file2.pdf was larger than file1.pdf. The workaround was to prepend (appendpdf.pl -p) file1.pdf to file2.pdf. This is fixed in CAM::PDF 1.54.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to do it from Perl? Chris has already mentioned [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF).

If you just need to merge them, [pdftk (PDF ToolKit)](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) works just fine. It's a simple command line:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output merged.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) utility `pdf2ps` to convert the PDFs into PostScript files, concatenate the PostScript files, and then use `ps2pdf` to convert the result back into a PDF.

Comment: I think it's because your solution doesn't use Perl.

Comment: Just because it's not a native Perl solutions doesn't mean it isn't any good.  Perl can very easily invoke other utilities via the shell.

Answer (score -2):

[Perlmonks has a fine discussion of this topic with, well, more than one way to do it.](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=470301)