# Merging PDF file on Windows with perl

Tags: perl, pdf

I need a way to merge PDF files on Windows using perl, it has to be perl because it is part of my script to organize a directory on Windows server. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge PDF files with Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419244/how-can-i-merge-pdf-files-with-perl)

Answer (score 3):

See this very related question: [How can I merge PDF files with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419244/how-can-i-merge-pdf-files-with-perl).

If the [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?appendpdf.pl) module doesn't suit you (if you can't get it on your Windows environment), the [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) mentioned there is available for Windows (see [Installing pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/)). You can use that from your perl scripts.

Please have a look at the [PDF Processing with Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/09/20/pdf-processing-with-perl.html) article for other options.

Comment: Yeah I saw that question already, but I thought it sounded more linux oriented.

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial to write a program that parses two PDF files, manipulates them, and writes them back out as a single merged file.  But if I were to dive into the task I would probably use the cpan module [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.019/lib/PDF/API2.pm).  It seems to be one of the most complete and most robust PDF modules on CPAN, though not necessarily the simplest to figure out.  There are other PDF modules under the PDF::***** heirarchy on CPAN, and some of them may provide just enough functionality for you, with less of a learning curve.

But let me suggest something else:  If you can find a ready-made tool that will merge two PDF files, you could allow Perl to send the files through that program, and retrieve the results.  This might be a simpler approach, and one that you can be reasonably certain already works (as opposed to you spending a lot of time debugging your own solution).  Your existing Perl script could interface with an external program that already has the capability you need.